# Are square tiled surfaces dense in the moduli space of translation surfaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading the survey "An introduction to Veech surfaces" by Pascal Hubert and Thomas Schmidt.

At page 19 they state "In any fixed stratum, the set of square-tiled surfaces of that stratum is dense.". The reason should be that in the coordinates for the moduli space of translation surfaces given by the period map (integration of the 1-form on relative periods) the coordinates of the translation surfaces are exactly $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$. So the assertion follows because of the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Well, it's hard for me to believe in Hubert and Schmidt's assertion.

Isn't it true that the square tiled surfaces are the "integer points" of the moduli space of translation surfaces? If I have a translation surface tiled by squares with the side of length one, isn't it true that the relative periods are contained in $\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$?

So my questions are:

Is Hubert and Schmidt's assertion wrong?

If so, which are the translation surfaces corresponding to rational points?

Thank you

Comment: Please give some more background. Is it clear that squares are supposed to have side length $1$? Which geometric structure is considered - conformal?

Comment: they don't specify it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Hubert and Schmidt's assertion wrong?

No, they are correct.  They allow squares where the sidelength is not equal to one.

If you like, we can say that the two translation surfaces $(X, \omega)$ and $(X, r\omega)$ (for $r$ positive and real) are "scalar multiples" of each other.  Then under any definitions, the scalar multiples of the square-tiled surfaces are dense in the space of translation surfaces.

**EDIT**: There is some nonsense (due to me) in the comments below.  Caveat emptor!

Comment: I see... But isn't this true only in the **space** of translation surfaces $\mathcal{T}:=\{(X,\omega)\}$? $(X,\omega)$ and $(X,r\omega)$ are isomorphic as translation surfaces, so in the **moduli space** of translation surfaces $\mathcal{T}/Diff^+$ the rational multiples should be all the same point

Comment: Ok - I am not using language the way you want me to - for that I apologize.  So I will back up a bit.  Suppose that $S$ is a topological surface (closed, connected, oriented).  Let $\hat{Q}(S)$ be the space of all pairs $(X, \omega)$ where (i) $X$ is a Riemann surface marked by $S$ and (ii) $\omega$ is a one-form.  We form a quotient $Q(S)$ by taking $(X, \omega)$ to be equivalent to $(X', \omega')$ if there is a biholomorphic map $h {:}\, X \to X'$ that (a) commutes (up to isotopy) with the markings and (b) pulls $\omega'$ back to $\omega$.  Now...

Comment: there is a forgetful map from $Q(S)$ to Teichmuller space $T(S)$ obtained by forgetting $\omega$. Set $Q(X)$ to be the fiber of this map over the point $[X] \in T(S)$.  I claim that $Q(X)$ is naturally homeomorphic to the vector space of one-forms on $X$. Square-tiled surfaces (where I allow scaling by a real number) are dense in that vector space, and thus in $Q(X)$, and thus in $Q(S)$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it now: it works because the scaling won't be isotopic to the identity?

Comment: No.  It works because scaling is not relevant.  You can't "really" tell the difference between $\omega$ and $r\omega$.  In a similar fashion - the union of the lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (through the origin and of rational slope) are dense.

Comment: @SamNead the statement 'square-tiled surfaces are dense in the fiber over $[X]$' implies that every Riemann surface $X$ admits a square-tiled surface structure. I presume this discussion implies that the above is true. Is there an easier/direct way to see that every Riemann surface $X$ admits a square-tiled surface structure?

Comment: An interesting corollary of the statement 'every Riemann surface $X$ admits a square-tiled surface structure' is that every Riemann surface $X$ admits a branched cover over the square torus, branched over at most one point of the square torus.

Comment: Well, crud.  I have definitely made a mistake.  There is no way your second consequence holds.  (Reason - there are only countably many topological branched-over-one-point covers of the torus.  Each of these gives a curve (complex dimension one) in moduli space.  But in higher genus moduli space has dimension at least two - it is not a countable union of curves.)

Comment: @MohithRaju - I deduce that square-tiled need not be dense in $Q(X)$.  But perhaps that is ok.  We don't need square-tiled surfaces in every fibre.  We just need them close to every quadratic differential.  _That_ is still true, because it is true in period coordinates.

Comment: And these annoying Riemann surfaces $X$, which are never square-tiled... well, their fibres $Q(X)$ are sort of like curves in the plane which don't go through any rational points.  Like, say, the line $y = x + \pi$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @SamNead Thanks, this makes things clear. Could you provide a good reference or two which covers some of the background more rigorously and talks about these aspects? Nuxil mentions "An introduction to Veech surfaces" by Pascal Hubert and Thomas Schmidt. Is there any other?

Comment: I learned a lot from Alex Wright's article "Translation surfaces and their orbit closures: An introduction for a broad audience".  On page two he references many more introductions; I've heard good things about the papers by Yoccoz and Zorich (and I am sure that the others are also very good!).

Comment: @SamNead, Could you please check whether the below pictorial proof is valid?

Comment: Looks good to me! I have been taught to say “differentials with rational coordinates are square-tiled and also are *obviously* dense”. Your proof is a nice way to get rid of that unpleasant word ‘obviously’.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more pictorial proof.

First, any translation surface can be obtained by choosing a suitable polygon and identifying pairs of parallel sides via translations.

Second, a **tetris polygon** is a polygon whose sides are all equal and are parallel to either the $x$-axis or $y$-axis.

Third, a **tetris-like translation surface** is a translation surface obtained from a tetris polygon after identifications of pairs of parallel sides via adequate translations.

Note that all tetris-like translation surfaces are square-tiled surfaces.

Figure 1 shows two examples of tetris-like translation surfaces.

[image: Figure 1]

Now to show square-tiled surfaces are dense among translation surfaces, it suffice to find tetris-like translation surfaces arbitrarily close to every translation surface.

Say, for e.g., we are given the translation surface $X$ obtained by identifying opposite sides of a diamond (See Figure 2).

[image: Figure 2]

Next, Figure 3 shows a tetris-like translation surface that is close $X$.

[image: Figure 3]

Now by making the vertical and horizontal sides smaller and bringing the jagged line closer to the diagonal edge of $X$, we get a tetris-like translation surface that is arbitrarily close to $X$.

More generally, any polygon can be approximated by a tetris polygon. Thus, tetris-like translation surfaces are dense in the space of all translation surfaces.